# Why does python change the value in this list?

Tags: python, list

So this is my code but I can't understand why python behaves like that

```
row1 = ['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']
row2 = ['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']
row3 = ['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']

map = [row1, row2, row3]

selectedRow = map[1]
selectedRow = ['X', '⬜️', '⬜️']

for row in map:
    print(row)
```

returns:

```
['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']
['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']
['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']
```

but with

```
selectedRow = map[1]
selectedRow[0] = "X"
```

returns :

```
['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']
['X', '⬜️', '⬜️']
['⬜️', '⬜️', '⬜️']
```

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedRow` is a variable, it did not store the value, it point to the value in the memory, it is just a name for humans to use.

```py
selectedRow = ['X', '⬜️', '⬜️']
```

means `selectedRow` point to a new list, the new list and the map are independent of each other, so when you change the new list value, the map's value is not affected.

`selectedRow[0]` point the map's value, so when you change it, equals you change the map's value.

Comment: "selectedRow[0] point the map's value, so when you change it, equals you change the map's value." Not exactly, `selectRow[i]` is just basically the method call `selectRow.__getitem__(i)`, and `selectRow[i] = value` is just `selectRow.__setitem__(i, value)`. The *type* defines what those methods do, the *could* mutate the object, but they don't *have* to. Of course, for `list` objects, they do